# Force refresh of a view after segue

Tags: ios

My App's UI runs in a circle, and after a single revolution, all my textfields need to change to reflect the received inputs from the previous cycle, preferably without direct user interaction.

I've found the function setNeedsDisplay, but getting it to call at the correct moment is my problem. AFAIK, a view only ever calls viewDidLoad once at its inception, so I'm at a loss where to stick it.

How can I force my views to refresh, preferably after a segue?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` & `viewDidAppear` is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to call it in the `-viewDidAppear` or `-viewWillAppear` method as it is called every time you go on your view.